# Async pipe not working with Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject-observer

I have the following BehaviorSubject in a service:

```
  isAuthenticated = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

And I am using it as follows in a component:

```
  authenticated: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authenticated = this.accountService.isAuthenticated.asObservable();
  }
```

And in the template I do something like :

```
  <li class="login-button" *ngIf="!authenticated | async">
    <a (click)="authenticate()">Log in</a>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="authenticated | async">
    <a>Logged in</a>
  </li>
```

The issue is that I dont see any of the two `li`, although the assumption is that the first one should appear since I am assigning the initial value of the Subject to false.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should be setting the value by calling the `next` method of the `BehaviourSubject`

Comment: Can you try putting the first expression into parenthesis like `!(authenticated | async)` to make sure it's using the `async` pipe on the Observable and not the result of `!authenticated`

Comment: @martin that's it! Thank you!

Comment: @Aravind, there is no need to call `next` for BehaviourSubject !

Comment: The initial value for the BehaviorSubject is 'false', which in your check ... *ngIf="authenticated" isn't going to give you anything. So yes it has a value, but not one that you code will find useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect its the order of operations - you need parenthesis around your subscription:

```
<li class="login-button" *ngIf="!(authenticated | async)">
```

Answer (score 5):

I thought of posting a solution using **[ng-if-else](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)** which is maybe even more intuitive in your particular case:

```html
<li class="login-button" *ngIf="(authenticated | async); else unauthenticated">
  <a>Logged in</a>
</li>
<ng-template #unauthenticated>
  <a (click)="authenticate()">Log in</a>
</ng-template>
```

Alternatively you could puth both cases inside a `ng-template:`

```html
<li class="login-button" *ngIf="(authenticated | async); then authenticated else unauthenticated"></li>
<ng-template #authenticated ><a>Logged in</a></ng-template>
<ng-template #unauthenticated><a (click)="authenticate()">Log in</a></ng-template>
```

Hope it is of any use to other people ending up here.